# Updating Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Variable During Release

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a classic Release Pipeline that has a few custom variables set that are used periodically throughout the release.

The first two steps in the release are two PowerShell scripts. In the first one, I basically take one of the variables, and assign a value to it. I then output what the variable was updated to so I can make sure it is correct (it always is). The second script does basically the same thing but to a different variable, and when I output the value, it is always correct.

Now, as the release is going, if I switch to the Variables tab, I can see the variable was never updated. It is still set at the value from the previous release. This is a major issue for me because about half way down the release, I have a "Copy Files" step, where it copies files to a folder path that is created from those variables. Since the variables are from the previous release, they are put into an improperly named folder path.

After the release pipeline is completed finished and succeeds, the Pipeline Variables are then correctly updated on the Variables tab.

Is there a way that I can update these variables DURING the release, instead of them updating after the release has completed? I would prefer to update them properly in my PowerShell scripts, or as a setting in the pipeline.

This is basically what my scripts looks like:

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/Release/definitions/$($env:RELEASE_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=5.0-preview.3"

$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

$buildNumber = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
$pipeline.variables.ReleaseVersion.value = $buildNumber

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99

$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

write-host "=================================" 
write-host "The value of ReleaseVersion updated to " $updatedef.variables.ReleaseVersion.value
write-host "================================="
```

My variable (ReleaseVersion in the script above) is set in the Variables tab, it's scope is 'Release', and 'Settable at release time' is checked. I have also tried using `Write-Host '##vso[task.setvariable variable=ReleaseVersion]$(Build.BuildNumber)'` to set my variable, but I get the same outcome.

UPDATE
ADDING NEW SCRIPT AND LOG DESCRIPTION

So I just pushed new code through my pipeline. The build was numbered `v2.1.0.16` (which is correct). I have the build number set to the branch name, plus a `(:.rev)` variable at the end.

The first script in the pipeline sets a custom pipeline variable called `ReleaseVersion`. It is set to the build number. This is the script:

```
 $url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/Release/definitions/$($env:RELEASE_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=5.0-preview.3"

$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

$buildNumber = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
$pipeline.variables.ReleaseVersion.value = $buildNumber

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99

$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

write-host "=================================" 
write-host "The value of ReleaseVersion updated to " $updatedef.variables.ReleaseVersion.value
write-host "================================="
```

and my output:

```
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5631557Z     "id":  #,
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5632209Z     "name":  "#",
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5632816Z     "path":  "#",
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5633410Z     "projectReference":  null,
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5634223Z     "url":  "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/definitions/{definitionId}",
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5635058Z     "_links":  {
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5635643Z                    "self":  {
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5636500Z                                 "href":  "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/definitions/{definitionId}"
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5637445Z                             },
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5641618Z                    "web":  {
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5643197Z                                "href":  "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/definitions/{definitionId}"
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5644085Z                            }
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5647518Z                }
2020-05-11T03:02:21.5648322Z }
2020-05-11T03:02:22.4291104Z =================================
2020-05-11T03:02:22.4456531Z The value of ReleaseVersion updated to  v2.1.0.15
2020-05-11T03:02:22.4483349Z =================================
2020-05-11T03:02:23.0643676Z ##[section]Finishing: Update Release Version
```

It says the value has been updated to `v2.1.0.15`, which is one revision behind the current build. I then have a script to make a folder path based on the above variable. It checks for a folder with that name (`v2.1.0.15` for example), and will attach a `-1` if it was already found, and a `-2` if the `-1` was already found, and so-on. It sets that folder name to a custom pipeline variable called `RootDirectory`. This is the script:

```
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/Release/definitions/$($env:RELEASE_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=5.0-preview.3"

$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
write-host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

$rootDirectory = $pipeline.variables.BuildDirectory.value + "\" + $pipeline.variables.ReleaseVersion.value

if (test-path $rootDirectory) {
    $newDirectory=$rootDirectory
    $index=0
    while (test-path $newDirectory) {
        $index += 1
        $newDirectory=$rootDirectory + "-" + $index
    } 
}

$pipeline.variables.RootDirectory.value = $newDirectory

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99

$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

write-host "=================================" 
write-host "The value of Root Directory updated to " $updatedef.variables.RootDirectory.value
write-host "================================="
```

The `BuildDirectory` variable is a hardcoded variable that never changes. And it's output:

```
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7255688Z     "id":  #,
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7255852Z     "name":  "#",
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7256001Z     "path":  "#",
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7256166Z     "projectReference":  null,
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7256379Z     "url":  "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/definitions/{definitionId}",
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7256556Z     "_links":  {
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7256698Z                    "self":  {
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7256903Z                                 "href":  "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/definitions/{definitionId}"
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7257174Z                             },
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7257331Z                    "web":  {
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7257537Z                                "href":  "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/definitions/{definitionId}"
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7257721Z                            }
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7257862Z                }
2020-05-11T15:32:45.7258016Z }
2020-05-11T15:32:46.6474274Z =================================
2020-05-11T15:32:46.6481861Z The value of Root Directory updated to  
2020-05-11T15:32:46.6491120Z =================================
2020-05-11T15:32:46.7209281Z ##[section]Finishing: Create Root Directory
```

Notice how the output of that script is blank, it does not show what the variable was updated to.

A few steps later in my pipeline, is where I actually use those variables. It is in a "Copy files" pipeline task. The target folder is set to `$(RootDirectory)/Debug`, but since the RootDirectory variable isn't updated, it just copies the files to the root c: drive.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I've had a lot going on and haven't gotten back to this. I will have an update for you tomorrow. Thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 0):

When I used code above with REST API ReleaseVersion remained the same as it was. However, I used logging command `Write-Host '##vso[task.setvariable variable=ReleaseVersion]$(Build.BuildNumber)'` and ReleaseVersion was updated but a new value was available in next step. So the new value should be available in `Copy Files` as it is a next step.

Comment: Hmm. I'll try this again in the morning. This has had me stumped for almost a week, so I've tried a lot of different combos. Thanks for your input. Any idea why one way works and the other doesn't?

Comment: In my copy files task, I call the variable from the Variables tab like `$(ReleaseVersion)/Debug`, do I need to call the variable differently if I want to get the variable from an earlier task instead of the Variables tab?

Comment: @dotnetdev, you do not need to call the variable differently, just use `$(ReleaseVersion)`

Answer (score 0):

> Updating Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Variable During Release

First, the reason why the [logging command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) not work for you is that:

The variable set by the logging command can only be used **inside the current agent**, and will not modify the value of the **web potral variable**.

So, we could use the set variable in the next task, but if you want to update the variable **on the Variables tab**, you could use the REST API ([Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)) to update the value of the release definition variable from a release pipeline:

```
PUT https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.0
```

Then, I have checked your scripts, it is close to the correct answer. The reason why it doesn't work for you is that you use variable `$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI)` in your `url`.

The default value of that variable is `https://dev.azure.com/YourOrganization/`. However, the API we use is that `https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}`, missing `vsrm` in the Url.

You could check my previous thread for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this. since my `URL` doesn't include the `vsrm`, should I just hardcode the `URL` and include it? Or is there another environment variable I can use that will include the `vsrm` in the` URL`? Judging by your answer, the rest of my script is correct, the only issue is the missing `vsrm` in the `URL`?

Comment: @dotnetdev, Yes, you can check my another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249440/set-azure-devops-release-pipeline-variable-using-rest-api/59259869#59259869

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve my issue. I reworked the URL so it is `$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1"` (and checked the output to ensure it was correct) but my pipeline is still behaving the same. My script will say  `The value of ReleaseVersion updated to master.10` (which is correct), but the variables tab isn't updated until after the pipeline completes (sometimes it is never updated), so using that variable later on in the pipeline always gives me whatever the old value was.

Comment: Should I be using the logging command, or my `$pipeline.variables.ReleaseVersion.value = $buildNumber` declaration to update the variable on the Variables tab?

Comment: @dotnetdev, variables tab isn't updated? You mean powershell script works fine, but the variable in the variables tab isn't updated? Would you mind share your powershell scripts and log in your question, you could check my previous thread, it should works fine.

Comment: @dotnetdev, you need use `$pipeline.variables.ReleaseVersion.value = $buildNumber`

Comment: @dotnetdev, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I added my two powershell scripts, and their outputs. I also explained the "copy files" task I am using, and what it's result is.