# Is it possible to forward an azure artifact from one pipeline to another?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-artifacts

I'm doing a project where I want a intermediate pipeline to consume an artifact from another pipeline to later forward it to another pipeline, which then starts running. I have not managed to find a solution online to this functionality and I'm starting to think that that functionality is not (as of today) supported in Azure DevOps. Can someone confirm whether this implementation is possible with pipelines? If not, how should one approach this scenario? I'm relatively new to Azure DevOps, so it's possible that I might have missed or misunderstood some information online.

I know that a pipeline can download an artifact which was published by another pipeline. And I know about pipeline triggers. Currently I have managed to consume artifacts in the intermediate pipeline, but now I have to find a way to send those artifacts to a specific pipeline, from the intermediate pipeline.

I appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but now I have to find a way to send those artifacts to a specific pipeline, from the intermediate pipeline.

We could **publish** build artifact from the **intermediate pipeline** by the [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) or [Publish Pipeline Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) task in the intermediate pipeline, then we use the [Download Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) or [Download Pipeline Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) task in the **specific pipeline** to **download** the artifact which we published from intermediate pipeline.

Yo could check this document [Publish and download artifacts in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for some more details.

**Update:**

> Are you aware if this functionality is planned for Azure DevOps? If we
> put it this way - is it possible for my intermediate pipeline to,
> depending on some variables, trigger a specific pipeline (i.e. it can
> trigger two different pipelines, but which one to trigger depends on
> some variables)?

The answer is yes. There is extension [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks), which can be used to trigger a new Build so that build-chaining is possible.

And we just need add the value of the variables as condition for this task, then we could trigger a specific pipeline depending on some variables.

> Where this specific pipeline is in another project. Is it also
> possible for this pipeline to access the variables which I created in
> my intermediate pipeline?

I think I might understand what you want to achieve. you want to create some variables in the intermediate pipeline, then use this variables in the specific pipeline.

The answer is yes. But there is no directly way to access the variables which you created in intermediate pipeline. The solution we need to set the default value for the variables in the specific pipeline, then use REST API [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/definitions/update?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to update those variables in the intermediate pipeline.

Please check [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249440/set-azure-devops-release-pipeline-variable-using-rest-api/59259869#59259869) for detailed REST API scripts.

Comment: I appreciate that you took the time to answer this. Are you aware if this functionality is planned for Azure DevOps? If we put it this way - is it possible for my intermediate pipeline to, depending on some variables, trigger a specific pipeline (i.e. it can trigger two different pipelines, but which one to trigger depends on some variables)? Where this specific pipeline is in another project. Is it also possible for this pipeline to access the variables which I created in my intermediate pipeline?

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. It looks like this will be the route I will take since what I originally had in mind doesn't seem to work with regards to the current functionality in Azure DevOps. But this solution will do.

Answer (score 2):

In complement to existing answers, I would like to add an example using `specificBuildWithTriggering` keyword.

Consider your initial pipeline that just saves an artifact:

```yaml
#artifact-creator.yml

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

stages:
  - stage: PublishArtifact
    jobs:
      - job: PublishArtifact
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "This is a sample text file." > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/sample.txt
            displayName: "Create sample.txt"

          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            inputs:
              targetPath: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
              artifact: "MyBuildArtifact"
            displayName: "Publish sample.txt artifact"
```

To correctly download the artifact using pipeline triggers, we will use [DownloadBuildArtifacts@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines) with `specificBuildWithTriggering`

```yaml
# artifact-downloader.yml

trigger: none
pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: artifact-creator
      source: artifact-creator
      trigger: true

stages:
  - stage: GetArtifact
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        steps:
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: "Download Artifact"
            inputs:
              buildType: specific
              project: myproject
              pipeline: artifact-creator
              specificBuildWithTriggering: true
              artifactName: MyBuildArtifact
              downloadPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/myartifact

          - script: |
              cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/myartifact/sample.txt
            displayName: "Display Artifact Contents"
```

It is important to use `buildType: specific` and not `current` as current will use the current build which will not contain the artifacts (which are built in the previous pipeline and therefore a previous build)

You should also replace `project: myproject` with the name of your project

Finally, `specificBuildWithTriggering: true` is the important part that makes sure that the artifacts are downloaded from the artifact-creator pipeline

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the solution would be adding Azure Artificats to store the output from Pipeline 1, then in Pipeline 2, download the artifact.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/overview?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this. And I agree with you, this currently seems like the only solution to this problem. I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution to this.