# How to get the value of $(Build.SourceVersionMessage) variable in Release Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

In the Release Pipeline under Release Notes, I am passing $(Build.SourceVersionMessage) but in my app center I am getting "$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)" as a string instead of the actual value. This variable works in my build pipeline under -task. How can I use this variable or any alternative way to fetch the commit message in the Release pipeline.

Comment: Are you referring to the [Classic Release pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops)? What type of artifact is used as input?

Comment: Try to set a variable on the release pipeline with the value of `$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)` for example `VersionMessage` and use this on your release pipeline as `$(VersionMessage)`

Comment: @danielorn Yes I am using Classic Release Pipeline and my Build Pipeline was created by Yaml. It's a Xamarin Forms application so my artifacts have (ios, android, uwp binaries).

Comment: @GeralexGR You mean to say that I need to create a variable "VersionMessage" in the release pipeline and set a value like "First commit" is it? If this is what you said then it will work but with every release I need to change the value of my variable(commit message) manually, which I don't want to do.

Comment: You should create a variable on the release pipeline with every name you want for example `VersionMessage` and set this variable value `$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)` . Then you can use on the release pipeline the `$(VersionMessage)` variable

Comment: @GeralexGR Release Pipeline variable Name **VersionMessage** and its value **$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)** and I referred in my release notes **$(VersionMessage)** but still, I can't able to fetch the value of Build.SourceVersionMessage is still as a string "$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)" in the app center.

Comment: @Nambukarthy is the release pipeline connected with the build pipeline with a CI/CD ?

Comment: @GeralexGR yeah, it is connected. In fact, I could able to get the value of $(Build.SourceVersion) variable also. It's only $(Build.SourceVersionMessage) variable's value I couldn't get.  Also, my deployment task works fine and it could able to get the artifacts of ios, android, and uwp properly and successfully deploy in the app center.

Comment: Another approach is to write `$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)` on a text file and use this text file and parse the value on the release pipeline, as it is not passed from build to release pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to get the value of $(Build.SourceVersionMessage) variable in Release Pipeline?

As we know the value of predefined variable $(Build.SourceVersionMessage) is the build pipeline, we could not get it from release pipeline directly.

To resolve this issue, there are three ways to do it：

1. Just as GeralexGR comment, writing `$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)` on a text file and publish this text file as artifact and parse the value in the release pipeline.
2. Using the REST API [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to update the variable with the value of `$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)` in the build pipeline. Or using [az pipelines variable-group variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/variable-group/variable?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-pipelines-variable-group-variable-update) to update the referenced variable group.

   You could check my [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249440/set-azure-devops-release-pipeline-variable-using-rest-api/59259869#59259869) for some more details.
3. You could combine your classic release pipeline and build YAML pipeline to one pipeline with multiple stages, then we could [use output variables from tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks):

   ```
    dependencies.JOB.outputs['TASK.VARIABLE']
   ```